# Random class seeds and nextInt effect on them based on seed value

Tags: java, random

So I have chopped up the code in an effort to clean this up a bit. My confusion is on B1 vs. B2. Is B2 just reaching the upper limit of what a Long value can be and that is why nextInt always returns a "1"? The assignment is to explain the behavior exhibited by each header (B1, B2...)

```
private static final long CONST1 = 340277109L;
private static final long CONST2 = 101010101L;
private static final long CONST3 = -5722202916L;
private static final long CONST4 = -1010101010L;
private static final long CONSTA = CONST1 + CONST2;
private static final long CONSTB = CONST3 + CONST4;
...
Random random = new Random(CONSTA);
System.out.print("B1: ");
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    System.out.print(random.nextInt(10) + " "); /* B1 */

System.out.print("\nB2: ");
random = new Random(CONSTB);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    System.out.print(random.nextInt(10) + " "); /* B2 */
```

Output:

```
B1: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
B2: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 4):

Java's `Random` implementation has a cycle length of 2<sup>48</sup>.  When you look at that long a sequence of truly random values ranging from 0 to 9, you will see runs of the same number repeated, runs up, runs down, and pretty much any other "unexpected" behavior you can imagine.  All of those "unexpected" behaviors actually occur in true randomness, so it's reasonable they should be observed in a pseudo-random number generator algorithm as well.  If they weren't, the PRNG would be provably non-random since such things occur with real randomness.

Nevertheless, the PRNG gives a deterministic sequence of length 2<sup>48</sup>.  When you choose a seed, you're selecting the point in the sequence at which you want to start tracking it.  You (or possibly your professor?) happen to have found a couple of seed values which start tracking at a couple of those "unexpected" behaviors.

Comment: Good answer. Let's put some numbers to it. What is the probability of getting 10 specific digits in a row? 1 in `10,000,000,000`. What is the number of combinations generated by 2⁴⁸? `281,474,976,710,656`. Statistically, how many times will the 10-digit sequence happen before the Random seed loops back on itself? **28,147 times**. It's just a matter of finding them.

Comment: @Andreas About the only thing I'd add to your comment is that 28,147 is the *expected* number of occurrences like that.  The actual number should be in that ballpark, but not necessarily (or even likely) that specific value.  If not, you've just invented a new test for PRNGs that catches Java's `Random` in a bad behavior.

Comment: True, which is why I prefaced the statement with "statistically". ;-)

Comment: Had my computer run overnight searching for long sequence of `1` values using `nextInt(10)`. Found seed `22317321631415L` as the start of a sequence of **13** consecutive `1` values. See [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/eTYDK4).

Comment: @Andreas Fun stuff!  I'm curious what seed produces the longest sequence of identical digits for any of the 10, and what that length is.  I'll have to give it a whirl when I have more spare time.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't hitting the max value of `Long`, it would appear your `CONSTA` (and `CONSTB`) are very poor seed(s) for [`Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html).

```
final long CONST1 = 340277109L;
final long CONST2 = 101010101L;
final long CONSTA = CONST1 + CONST2;
System.out.println(CONSTA + " " + Long.toBinaryString(CONSTA));
```

Outputs

```
441287210 11010010011011000001000101010
```

Comment: Well, I agree that they are all bad seeds, but I think that is probably the point that he is trying to show. However with the CONSTA only value it will generate is a 1, when comparing between it and 10. As for CONSTB I understand it even less. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)

Comment: @YeeP `CONSTA` (and `CONSTB`) generate different values. Try looping to `100`. It's only your initial range that is *easily* predictable (assuming you don't know the **seed**).

Comment: @YeeP They are **NOT** bad seeds, there's not really any such a thing.  See my explanation of what a seed does.  Seeds can produce rare outcomes, but if seed values are themselves selected randomly that should happen (ahem!) rarely.